# How to Increase Column Space in EXtJS Column Layout

Tags: extjs4

i have designed an entry form as shown,

i need to have same space between **test box and Middle name label**.

My code is as follows,

```
var patientForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
layout: 'column',
columnWidth:1.5,
renderTo: "patientCreation",
frame: true,
autoScroll:true,
title: 'Create Patient',
bodyStyle: 'padding:9px',           
width: 900,
items: [
{   xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'FirstName',
    name: 'firstName',
    vtype : 'alpha',
    allowBlank:false
},{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'MiddleName',
    name: 'middleName',
    vtype : 'alpha'             
},{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'LastName',
    name: 'lastName',
    vtype : 'alpha',
    allowBlank:false
},{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Email',
    name: 'email',
    vtype: 'email',
    allowBlank:false
},
....
....
]
```

How to leave/increase space between **text box and Middle name** column?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your number of columns, use column layout. Otherwise do this:

```
defaults: {
    labelStyle: 'padding-left:10px;'
},
items: [...]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur comment,It works good.Also is there any way to make all the labels in a single line..??

Comment: You're welcome. What do you mean by making all labels in a single line? (In your codes?)

Comment: If u see 'Emergency Contact' label it is breaked in two lines ,i want to make it in single line.

Comment: can u please elaborate how to use 'label Width' bcoz i m very new to ExtJs

Comment: Sure. Do this: defaults: { 
    labelStyle: '...', labelWidth: 200 
}

Comment: Thanks for ur comments ,i have another question regarding JSON parsing,can u help me for that..?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `defaults` config to the container of the columns. All it's children will have the settings you define in `defaults` ([docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-cfg-defaults)). In this example there's just the `margin` setting ([docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-margin)) in `defaults` that will be applied to each item/column.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
  title: 'Column Layout - with default margins',
  width: 350,
  height: 250,
  layout:'column',
  defaults: {
    margin: '0 15 0 0' //top right bottom left (clockwise) margins of each item/column
  },
  items: [{
    title: 'Column 1',
    columnWidth: 0.25
  },{
    title: 'Column 2',
    columnWidth: 0.55
  },{
    title: 'Column 3',
    columnWidth: 0.20
  }],
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

The accepted solution works only with fields as columns. My solution works with any type of column.

PS: the column layout documentation is [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Column).